# JSON parse double quotes in string literal

Tags: javascript, json

I am having problem parsing quotes in string literal.

```
var lit = '{"foo":"test \"1\"","bar":"test 2"}';
```

In console, this gives an error 'Uncaught exception'.
I am expecting:

```
Object {foo: "test "1"", bar: "test 2"}
```

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bruceradtke/kor8amm5/4/

It works ok if I assign stringify result to variable and then 
parse that variable.  But not if I use string literal as above.

Thanks.

My code:

```
var myobject = {};
myobject.foo = "test \"1\"";
myobject.bar = "test 2";

var sresult = JSON.stringify(myobject);
console.log('stringify=' + sresult);
// OK
var thaw = JSON.parse(sresult);
console.log( thaw);

var lit = '{"foo":"test \"1\"","bar":"test 2"}';
console.log(lit);
// Broken
var thaw2 = JSON.parse(lit);
```

Comment: That's because you have the JSON inside a **string literal**. Inside a string literal, \ is the escape character. So if you want to produce a literal \, you have to escape it : \\ . But why do you have that in the first place? Is it just for testing?

Answer (score 20):

Remember that you are escaping two string literals: one for declaring the property and one for declaring the variable (`lit`). So you need to escape your escape character: `"test \\"1\\""`

```js
var lit = '{"foo":"test \\"1\\"","bar":"test 2"}';
console.log(lit);

var thaw2 = JSON.parse(lit);
```

Comment: This is correct. +1 Updated OP's fiddle in case that helps him/her: https://jsfiddle.net/kor8amm5/5/

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I had a similar problem and your solution worked fine for me.
However, I'm still not completely understanding why we're escaping two string literals.

Comment: @LeandroCaplan: It's because there's a string literal inside a string literal. The original string is `test "1"`. The string literal representing that string is `"test \"1\""` (escaping `"` with a backslash). The string literal representing _that_ string could be `"\"test \\\"1\\\"\""` (escaping both `"` and `\` characters by putting `\` before them). We can avoid escaping the double-quotes that last time by using single-quotes for the string literal, but that doesn't prevent us from needing to escape the backslashes: `'"test \\"1\\""'`