# Unable to get the data from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting below response from a service call :

```
var response =  "\"   {\\\"errcode\\\":1,\\\"errmsg\\\":\\\"ok\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"https:\\\\/\\\\/mp.weixin.qq.com\\\\/cgi-bin\\\\/showqrcode?ticket=gQH38DwAAAAAAAAAAS5odHRwOi8vd2VpeGluLnFxLmNvbS9xLzAyYTZKU1pzczJhdmUxWHZ6MzFvMTcAAgTfurtYAwQA6QcA\\\"}\""
```

I decode that and got

```
var responseAfterDecode = decodeURI(response);
```

// responseAfterDecode

```
"{\"errcode\":1,\"errmsg\":\"ok\",\"data\":\"https:\\/\\/mp.weixin.qq.com\\/cgi-bin\\/showqrcode?ticket=gQH38DwAAAAAAAAAAS5odHRwOi8vd2VpeGluLnFxLmNvbS9xLzAyYTZKU1pzczJhdmUxWHZ6MzFvMTcAAgTfurtYAwQA6QcA\"}"
```

After that I parsed the JSON:

```
var JSONAfterParse = JSON.parse(responseAfterDecode);
```

// JSONAfterParse =

```
{"errcode":1,"errmsg":"ok","data":"https:\/\/mp.weixin.qq.com\/cgi-bin\/showqrcode?ticket=gQH38DwAAAAAAAAAAS5odHRwOi8vd2VpeGluLnFxLmNvbS9xLzAyYTZKU1pzczJhdmUxWHZ6MzFvMTcAAgTfurtYAwQA6QcA"}
```

This looks like a perfect JSON. But when I tried to access

```
JSONAfterParse.data --> undefined.
```

Unable to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: What does JSONAfterParse.errcode return?

Comment: undefined, when I ran on few online JSONQuery tools, I am getting perfect response, don't know what is wring here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you actually have double-stringified JSON (the string representation of the string representation of JSON). That means after a single `JSON.parse`, you still get a string back (hence the lack of any `data` property). Yuck. However, you can fix your problem by parsing the JSON again:

```js
var response =  "\"   {\\\"errcode\\\":1,\\\"errmsg\\\":\\\"ok\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"https:\\\\/\\\\/mp.weixin.qq.com\\\\/cgi-bin\\\\/showqrcode?ticket=gQH38DwAAAAAAAAAAS5odHRwOi8vd2VpeGluLnFxLmNvbS9xLzAyYTZKU1pzczJhdmUxWHZ6MzFvMTcAAgTfurtYAwQA6QcA\\\"}\""

var responseAfterDecode = decodeURI(response)

var jsonAfterParse = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(responseAfterDecode))

console.log(jsonAfterParse.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access a property from a STRING and not from an Object, you need to use `JSON.parse(string)`...

```js
var JSONAfterParse = '{"errcode":1,"errmsg":"ok","data":"https:\/\/mp.weixin.qq.com\/cgi-bin\/showqrcode?ticket=gQH38DwAAAAAAAAAAS5odHRwOi8vd2VpeGluLnFxLmNvbS9xLzAyYTZKU1pzczJhdmUxWHZ6MzFvMTcAAgTfurtYAwQA6QcA"}';
var ParsedJSON = JSON.parse(JSONAfterParse);
console.log(ParsedJSON.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var response =  "\"   {\\\"errcode\\\":1,\\\"errmsg\\\":\\\"ok\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"https:\\\\/\\\\/mp.weixin.qq.com\\\\/cgi-bin\\\\/showqrcode?ticket=gQH38DwAAAAAAAAAAS5odHRwOi8vd2VpeGluLnFxLmNvbS9xLzAyYTZKU1pzczJhdmUxWHZ6MzFvMTcAAgTfurtYAwQA6QcA\\\"}\""

var responseAfterDecode = decodeURI(response);

var js =JSON.parse(responseAfterDecode);
js = JSON.parse(js);

console.log(js.data);
```

Ref: [JSON parse double quotes in string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416529/json-parse-double-quotes-in-string-literal)

[JSON Parsing the string to object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)